# asp.net: line break \n in resource .resx file does not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, line-breaks, resx, resource-files

The "\n" does not work in below code, it's just displayed as "\n"

```
if (!window.confirm(XXXXX.Globalization.LocalResource.InvalidUrl)) {
    return false;
}
```

the string is "Invalid URL! \n Are you sure you want to continue?" in resource resx file.

how to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try shift-enter to create a new line in the designer. Alternatively copy and paste the result from notepad.

Another way is to edit the RESX xml manually.

The problem is that the RESX designer UI will auto-escape the strings. So your value is actually:

```
"Invalid URL! \\n Are you sure you want to continue?"
```

Answer (score 11):

What worked in my case was this:

```
This text has a<br>line break!
```

See the `<br>` there.

Look here for the details: [Putting a line break in an resx resource file](http://scottstoecker.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/putting-a-line-break-in-an-resx-resource-file/)

I'm using Razor in ASP.NET MVC and so I used:

```
@Html.Raw(Localization.NotAnswered)
```

so that it outputs the `<br>` as HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I used shift+enter, it think it's the simplest.

< br >certainly will not work, have not tried \r\n, but since \n does not work, I am not very confident with \r\n

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC 
STEP-1
In my `Resource.resx` file put `Shift+Enter` between the paragraph1 & paragraph2
My text paragraph1
My text paragraph2

STEP-2
In my view page its

```
<p>@Html.Raw(Regex.Replace(Resource.Mytext, "\r\n", "<br />"))</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `&lt;br&gt;` if editing raw file or use `<br>` if editing in IDE.

Details: If you create line breaks by just pressing Enter or Shift+Enter then the line breaks will not show up on a web page. Going back to HTML basics, if you want the browser to render line breaks then you must use a `<br>` tag. For me I was editing my resx file using a simple text editor, and the problem I encountered when adding a `<br>` tag is that when I later tried to open the file in Visual Studio it threw an error about "*the closing tag doesn't match*". It turns out that resx files don't allow you to use a `<br>` tag. You need to actually use `&lt;br&gt;`. In fact, if you're editing the file in Visual Studio and you enter `<br>` in the value field, it will automatically convert `<br>` to `&lt;br&gt;`. You won't see it in the IDE, but if you enter `<br>` in the IDE, save it, then open the raw file in Notepad++ you will see the actual value is `&lt;br&gt;`.

Answer (score -1):

Shift-enter works great when you're entering strings, but if you have already created your resource file, and you dont want to edit every string, you can just do

```
String myStringFromResx = myStringFromResx.Replace("\\n," "\n");
```

Comment: I'd use the Visual Studio Find and Replace to do it instead and then check it replaced the right things. Otherwise you have to sprinkle this through your code and might introduce a bug if you really want to print \n